# Subclassing UINavigationBar in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, subclass

I'm trying to create a custom `UINavigationBar` class and then use the `Storyboard` to set it as the class of my `UINavigationController`'s NavigationBar.

Here's the code of my `UINavigationBar` class:

```
class CustomNavBar: UINavigationBar {

    override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {
        super.drawRect(rect)
        // Drawing code
        self.backgroundColor = UIColor.orangeColor()

        let myLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 4, width: 600, height: 36))
        myLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor.purpleColor()
        myLabel.textColor = UIColor.yellowColor()
        myLabel.text = "Custom NavBar!"

        self.addSubview(myLabel)
    }

}
```

Then, in Interface Builder, I use the `Identity Inspector` to set this as the class of the `NavigationBar` of my `UINavigationController`.

When I run the App - it freezes. It hangs up on the `LaunchScreen.xib` and doesn't do anything.

Why is doing that? What's the right way to go about doing this?

Comment: maybe you need to call `super.drawRect` somewhere

Comment: that sounded right - but it didn't do it... (I'll add it to my code though, in the body of my question)

Comment: do you get any error message

Comment: No, it just freezes on the LaunchScreen.XIB screen- which is something I've never seen. Very weird. (To be clear: it isn't crashing, it isn't generating any errors - it just runs, then freezes on the LaunchScreen.)

Comment: Yeah, that is weird. I was able to duplicate that and I have no idea why that occurs. You could try just subclassing UINavigationController and editing the navigationBar property of that in viewDidLoad(). I just tested that and it doesn't freeze.

Comment: I did try to subclass UINavigationController - crashed all over the place :-) Can you share the code for subclassing UINavigationController? (Or should I post it in a different question and point you to it? Ultimately I'd like to give you credit for right answer.)

Comment: I just copy pasted your drawRect function into viewDidLoad of the subclassed NavigationController. I then replaced all of the `self`s with `navigationBar`. Then I just set the class in the storyboard. Didn't crash for me.

Comment: Yes, I see. That's cool. Doing it that way works for me as well - so thank you - but its not what I'm after. I still want to create a custom UINavigationBar **class** so I can truly reuse it, over and over again, throughout my App. Your solution is created with code - which would have to be copy-pasted into every ViewController we work with, and that kinda defeats the purpose - know what I mean?

Comment: Since you are subclassing UINavigationController, you wouldn't have to copy and paste the code into all your view controllers because they would share the same navigation controller.

Comment: that's true - but its still doesn't solve my original problem/question which is: how do you subclass `UINavigationBar`? This is something I would want to know not just for this App but for future projects. Its also about the larger issue of understanding the inner-workings and interactions between Xcode/Storyboards/Code, etc., know what I mean?

Comment: Yup, I totally agree. Unfortunately, I can't answer that.

Comment: All good :-) Regardless, it turns out subclassing `UINavigationBar` wouldn't have solved my problem anyway (which was figuring out how to install - _and handle_ - a menu item _globally_, as opposed to doing it in every single VC throughout the App.)  Its trickier than it sounds. I thought it would involve `UINavigationBar`, but it doesn't. Luckily a buddy just came up with the answer so I'm gonna let this go - AND, I'll credit you with the right answer anyway :-) (unless that'd be misleading to future users who do a search on this topic?) Waddaya think?

Comment: Nah, I don't think I answered your question. Glad you fixed it though.

Comment: I'm not surprised that it was crashing. `drawRect` gets called repeatedly whenever the view needs to be drawn by the system. So for each time it gets called you are adding another `myLabel` to the view hierarchy. By contrast the two `init` methods are only called the once: `init(frame: CGRect)` when you create a view in code and `init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder)` when it is coming from a nib.

Answer (score 4):

**On Swift:**

File-New-File- iOS Source - Cocoa Touch class- Select Subclass of : UINavigationBar  and Name it - CustomNavigationBar.

```
class CustomNavigationBar: UINavigationBar {

        override init(frame: CGRect) {
            super.init(frame: frame)

            self.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()

        }
        required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
            super.init(coder: aDecoder)!
        }
        override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {

        }   
    }
```