# Is it possible to add a UIView as UINavigationBar's background

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uinavigationbar

I'm trying to create a specific background to a `UINavigationBar`, but I don't want to use images or solid color, I have a custom `UIView` that i've created and in it's `drawRect` method I'm drawing some stuff, I want this to be the `UINavigationBar`'s background.

Is it possible?

This is my custom view:

```
class GradientColorView : UIView {

    var colors : NSArray = NSArray() {
        didSet {
            setNeedsDisplay()
        }
    }

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
    }

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

    override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {

        var topRect : CGRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, rect.size.width, rect.size.height / 2.0)
        var firstColor : UIColor = self.colors[0] as! UIColor
        firstColor.setFill()
        UIRectFill(topRect)

        var bottomRect : CGRect = CGRectMake(0, rect.size.height/2.0, rect.size.width, rect.size.height/2.0)
        var secondColor : UIColor = self.colors[1] as! UIColor
        secondColor.setFill()
        UIRectFill(bottomRect)
    }
}
```

And in Swift of course :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i've found the answer to my question, what I did is created a `UINavigationBar` subclass called `CustomNavigationBar` and override init method like that:

```
class CustomNavigationBar: UINavigationBar {

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

        self.backgroundColor = UIColor.someColor()
        let view : UIView = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 20, frame.size.width, 44))
        self.addSubview(view)
    }

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

    override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {

    }
}
```

Then I've added this method on the `UIViewController` that holds the `UINavigationBar`:

```
func styleCustomNavigationBar() {

    self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: false)
    var navigationBar : CustomNavigationBar = CustomNavigationBar(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, CGRectGetWidth(self.view.bounds), 64.0))
    var navigationItem : UINavigationItem = UINavigationItem()
    var backButton : UIBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Back", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, target: self, action: "backButtonDidClicked")
    navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = backButton
    navigationBar.items = [navigationItem]
    self.view.addSubview(navigationBar)
}
```

I used [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31116733/subclassing-uinavigationbar-in-swift) and question and [this](https://www.codeschool.com/blog/2014/11/11/ios-app-creating-custom-nav-bar/) website to reach solution.

Enjoy!